# Qt Button Focus

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I got any visible focus on buttons in Qt while press Tab key.

I was unchecked the auto default & default property of push buttons.

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setStyleSheet("QPushButton:focus { outline: 0 }");` on your button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking here.  If your question is that you cannot focus on your button on a Dialog? (..I am assuming) while you press the tab key; then you should also be setting the tab-order -- visually using Qt Designer, or with code in the concerned Dialog's constructor.

Read more about what the auto-default and default properties mean [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop)